# Vb.net get integers only from string with integers

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have this string  `123abc123` how can i get only integers from this string?

For example, convert `123abc123` to `123123`.

What i tried:

```
Integer.Parse(abc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the right method to extract the integers is using `isNumbric` function:

```
Dim str As String = "123abc123"
Dim Res As String
For Each c As Char In str
    If IsNumeric(c) Then
        Res = Res & c
    End If
Next
MessageBox.Show(Res)
```

another way:

```
Private Shared Function GetIntOnly(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Dim returnVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\d+")
    For Each m As Match In collection
        returnVal += m.ToString()
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt32(returnVal)
End Function
```

Comment: thank you again. how can i convert the Res string to integer number?

Comment: in this way: Integer.Prase(String)

Comment: @Nmmmm: perhaps `Parse`? My spellchecker suggests however `Praise`.

Comment: A word of caution: This method does a lot of conversion... Each character will be boxed in an object on the heap to be sent to the `IsNumeric` method, then concatenating each digit to the string creates a new string. Concatenating strings that way should only be used when you know that the strings can never be long, as it gets tremendously slow with longer strings.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx)

```
Dim str = "123abc123"
Dim onlyDigits = New String(str.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
Dim num = Int32.Parse(onlyDigits)
```

Comment: doesn't VB support syntax like `str.Where(Char.IsDigit)`?

Comment: @Vlad In VB you would have to write `str.Where(addressOf Char.IsDigit)`

Comment: there is a error : 'onlyDigits' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level (thank you to)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dim input As String = "123abc456"
    Dim reg As New Regex("[^0-9]")
    input = reg.Replace(input, "")
    Dim output As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(input, output)
```

Comment: you ought to not ignore the result of `TryParse`, better let it crash with just `Parse`. still +1

Comment: you are supposed to check the output whether the tryparse is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with the pattern `\D` to match non-digit characters and remove them, then parse the remaining string:

```
Dim input As String = "123abc123"

Dim n As Integer = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(input, "\D", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FindAll` to extract required stuff. we should also consider `Val` function to handle for an empty string.

```
    Dim str As String = "123abc123"
    Dim i As Integer = Integer.Parse(Val(New String(Array.FindAll(str.ToArray, Function(c) "0123456789".Contains(c)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Use Val() function of vb.net. https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/vbnet/val-function.html.

```
 Dim str As String = "123abc123"
 Dim result As Integer =Val(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_OnLoad() Handles Me.Load
    Dim str1 As String = "2,147,4abc83,648" '"123abc123"
    FindingNumbers(str1)
End Sub

Private Sub FindingNumbers(ByRef str1 As String)
    Dim str2 As String = ""
    For i = 0 To str1.Length - 1 Step 1
        Dim chr As Char = Mid(str1, i + 1, 1)
        Select Case chr
            Case "0" : str2 &= "0"
            Case "1" : str2 &= "1"
            Case "2" : str2 &= "2"
            Case "3" : str2 &= "3"
            Case "4" : str2 &= "4"
            Case "5" : str2 &= "5"
            Case "6" : str2 &= "6"
            Case "7" : str2 &= "7"
            Case "8" : str2 &= "8"
            Case "9" : str2 &= "9"
        End Select
    Next
    Try
        Dim num As Integer = 0 '(-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.)
        num = CType(str2, Integer)
        MsgBox("There was found the following number: " & Str(num), MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was a error in conversion to int from string.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        MsgBox("There was found the following number: " & str2, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```